# how to unwrap only one parent in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have optgroup in select menu, I want get rid of from it. I am using jquery unwrap method to get it done but it is removing whole select menu. here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5dN/)

```
$(function(){
   $('select').find('option').not(':first').parent().unwrap()
})
```

### HTML

```
<select>
    <option>select</option>
    <optgroup label="state">
        <option>new york</option>        
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="country">
        <option>us</option>        
    </optgroup>

</select>
```

Comment: Quote the markup **in the question**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('select').find('option').not(':first').unwrap();`

You have to unwrap the option not the *parent* of the option!

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5dN/10/

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$(function(){
   $('select').find('optgroup option').unwrap()
})
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5dN/4/)

Comment: you were trying to unwrap the parent

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function(){
   $('optgroup').find('option').unwrap();
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5dN/2/)